# Kentico v10 Is it possible to do a bulk export of files from the CMS media library to a folder on a PC?

Tags: export, kentico, media-library

We have built a file upload facility on our Kentico v10 website. External users upload documents into folders within the media library, and internal staff then need to extract these uploaded documents in order to work with them.

Is it possible to extract the documents in media library in bulk?

We have been told it is only possible to extract the files 1 at a time. There are over 500 a month being uploaded so this has been an unpopular solution with the staff who extract these documents.

It seems unlikely that Kentico would build a CMS that doesn't allow bulk exports from a media library, especially when they have a facility that allows files to be uploaded.

The link below shows a screenshot example of the problem. It is numerous files in the media library that require extracting in bulk. Currently we extract one by one.

![media library with documents requiring bulk extraction]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lDV1sL7CEtQoVqLoawgtd8r2m7O-bPBr/view?usp=sharing!

If anyone knows a way we can extract these files in bulk to a PC, your help is very much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, all files for media library are sitting already in a folder on server, so you could get an access to the particular folder and download it (maybe via FTP)...

Or there is an export feature which you may find handy in this case:

https://blogs.jeroenfurst.nl/blog/october-2015/quick-tip-how-to-export-a-media-library-with-files

Open zip folder, extract files in export{timestamp}.zip\Data\Files\media_files##SITENAME##{LibraryFolder}{LibraryName} and change the extension from File_Name.jpg.export to File_Name.jpg

Comment: Note that it's possible that media library images are configured to be stored in the Database. Although that's not common practice.

You can check this in the Settings application under "Settings > System > Files" it is configured in the top "Storage" section.

https://content.screencast.com/users/DavidTK/folders/Jing/media/82fa7f9d-d513-4251-9ddd-99fc26496840/2019-05-03_1105.png

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there is no way to simply export a given selection of files from the Media Library.  You can use the example Michal Samuhel gave from Kentico MVP, Jeroen Furst although that exports the whole library.

Your best case would be to create a custom webpart which will allow users to filter the media library files by date, then perform an export on them.  The downside, is if the media library files aren't "imported" into the media library, there is no database representation of them at all.

Another option is to modify your upload and email processing process:

- users upload to a directory in the media library
- you create a custom scheduled task which takes those new files, zips them up, saves the zip file to a download directory, then and sends an email with a link to download the files.
- the scheduled task takes those "exported" files and relocates them to a new directory for safe keeping.